# Android: Dynamically assigning resource id for Popup menu items

Tags: android, xml, menu, popup

Touching on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031750/how-to-set-id-for-popup-menu-items-to-be-found-as-view-id), I want to know the feasibility of creating resource ids for dynamically created popup menu items.

A little background: my popup menu contains a "create new file" item in addition to an item for every file found in a given directory. The problem; since I don't know how many files exist in the directory when the app is started, I can't hard code these menu items in my xml file, hence they have no resource ids. I need to assign resource ids for the items in my popup menu so I can create a View variable from an individual item's resource id, i.e:

```
View menuItemView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.item_id);
```

[I see](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) that one overloaded version of getMenu().add() accepts itemID as a parameter. Can I set this parameter with an int during runtime and then later reference it as a resource id for my purpose above?

This is my complete popup menu code, showcasing the way I dynamically generate menu items:

```
 popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.new_track:
                trackSelectButton.setText("...");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name your new track.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                txtTrackName.setVisibility(txtTrackName.VISIBLE);
                return true;

            default:
                selectedTrackName = (item.getTitle().toString());
                trackSelectButton.setText(selectedTrackName);
                for (int i = 0; i < trackListing.length; i++) { //add a menu item for each existing track
                    if (trackListing[i].getName().equals(selectedTrackName)) {
                        selectedTrack = trackListing[i];
                        AudioRecorder.setFile(selectedTrack);
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
});

MenuInflater popupInflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
popupInflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_track_selection, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
```

**How can I dynamically generate resource ids for popup menu items? (aka assigning resource ids without an xml file)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered [View.generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29)?  and [setId(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts).